# Image manipulate in lexical editor

Tags: editor, text-editor, lexicaljs

I am working on blog like web project using lexical editor in nextjs.
I am trying to implement image plugin in lexical editor. For now it coverts to base64 format which will be expensive for storing in database. Instead of storing base64 I want to store the image link along with other text inside database. Also I am facing issue to implement image plugin of lexical editor in nextjs.

steps I want to follow

- I want to upload image in aws s3 and then want to show in editor as image.
- Another way I am trying to implement like a modal will open where image can be selected
  and it uploads to aws s3 and gets image url, then want to show image url in editor.

Is there any solution for it?
Thanks in advance for any suggestion

Comment: I think second solution would be easier to implement than the first. But it comes at a cost of UX.